# Python3 does not write on file when invoked by Node js

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs

I am using Node and Python3 on my server side. Basically Node (as my backend) takes the data input from my frontend and invokes python that performs a series of tasks. All the tasks are performed in order and perfectly, except writing on file ("backUpData"). And what is weird is that if python3 is invoked from terminal, then it writes on file perfectly.

This is my python file:

```
def backUpData(data):
    ff = open("backup.txt",'a')
    ff.write(data+"\n")
    ff.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = " ".join(map(str,sys.argv[1:])).strip().lower()
    backUpData(data) #function that does not work when invoked by Node
    data = otherFunction1(data) #it works perfectly
    print(data) #this is what returned to Node
```

And this is Node invoking python:

```
async function searchWeb({ query }, res) {
      var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
      process = spawn("python", [pathToPython, "mypython.py", data]);
      process.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
      res.json({ reply: data.toString("utf8") });
  });
 }
```

I guess a solution would be to write directly from Node, but I am not here to find a secondary solution. I just would like to know why if I run on console

```
 $python3 mypython.py data
```

then it works perfectly and append data on the backup.txt file, while when node does it, it does not write on it.

python version is python3.5 and running the command python or python3.5 (from console) gives the same output since they are the same version.

Thanks!

Comment: The problems is most likely caused by relative path error. Try using the full path to the file in your python script when you are opening it.

Comment: @DobromirM that was it! Silly me, it was writing the whole time, just not on the same directory! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! I posted it as an answer as well so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spawn()` method in Node.js will likely start the python process with different relative path compared to running the python script from console. You will either need to use the absolute path to the file or change the relative path so that it can find the correct directory.